# Page not found (404) - The current path, poussaim/nouria/'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've been stuck for a while; I can't figure out what's wrong.
I want to display all the details about a customer (DetailView) and I get error 404.
Here's the url returned: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/poussaim/nouria/'](http://127.0.0.1:8000/poussaim/nouria/%27)
When I remove the apostrophe at the end of the url, the page is displayed correctly: http://127.0.0.1:8000/poussaim/nouria/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's my code

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from poussaim_app.views import *

app_name = "nrn"

urlpatterns = [
    path("contact/", signup, name="contact"),
    # Customer
    path("", HomeViewCustomer.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("<str:slug>/", DetailViewCustomer.as_view(), name="view-customer"),
    path("<str:slug>/deletecustomer/", DeleteViewCustomer.as_view(), name="delete-customer"),
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView, DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from poussaim_app.models import Customer

class HomeViewCustomer(ListView):
    """
    Page d'accueil, page principale avec la liste des clients enrégistrés

    """
    model = Customer  
    template_name = "index.html"
    context_object_name = "customes


class DetailViewCustomer(DetailView):
    """
    Vue info/détail d'un client

    """
    model = Customer
    template_name = "client/detail_client.html"
    context_object_name = "custome"

class DeleteViewCustomer(DeleteView):
    """
    Suppression d'un client

    """
    model = Customer
    template_name = "client/delete.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("nrn:home")
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    Table client: la liste des entreprises partenaires
    name: nom de l'entreprise

    """
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name="Nom du Client")

    gerant = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True, verbose_name="Nom du dirigeant ou son représentant")

    save_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer"
        ordering = ["-date_creation", "customer_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.customer_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("custome", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

client/detail_client.html

```
{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'nrn:delete-customer' slug=custome.slug %}"> Supprimer </a>
    <hr>
    <div id="client">
        <h3> Nom du client: {{ custome.customer_name }} </h3>
        <h3>Contact: </h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>{{ custome.gerant }} </li>
                <li>{{ custome.save_by }} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have configured your app URLs to start with - "/poussaim/" in your main url.py file. But as you told the link works when you remove the apostrophe, it should be so. The reason you get error 404 when having the apostrophe is because you haven't configured it to have it. Try using:-

```
path("<str:slug>/'", DetailViewCustomer.as_view(), name="view-customer"),
```

In this, you have specified it to have the apostrophe.

Comment: It doesn't work when I add the apostrophe at the end of the url path: path("<str:slug>/'", DetailViewCustomer.as_view(), name="view-customer"),
here's the url I get on my browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000/poussaim/nouria/''

Comment: Could I know why you add 2 apostrophes, if you want to, you can change the code like this to make it work.

path("<str:slug>/''", DetailViewCustomer.as_view(), name="view-customer"),

Note that I have added 2 apostrophes here and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
I finally found my error: it was in one of my templates html files (in the href) where there is this extra apostrophe.
THANKS

Comment: This is reply message; no answer.